# PHPMailer no funciona en GoDaddy

Tags: php, phpmailer

tengo el siguiente código:

```
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Host = "smtpout.secureserver.net";
    $mail->Username = "correo@midominio.com";
    $mail->Password = "password";
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->setFrom($correo, $nombre);
    //$mail->FromName = $nombre;
    $mail->AddAddress("correo@midominio.com", "Guillermo Spindola");
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = $asunto;
    $body = $mensaje;
    $mail->Body = $body;
    $exito = $mail->Send();
```

En XAMPP funciona perfectamente, ya eh realizado varias pruebas. Pero al momento de subirlo al hosting que tengo en GoDaddy no funciona.

Comment: La cuenta del mail esta creada bajo el dominio donde esta tu hosting? Para hacer una prueba rapida envia un mail con al funcion mail de php desde algun mail creado en el hosting y otro como un gmail por ejemplo (Si es gmail tenes que habilitar la opcion de enviar mails desde aplicaciones no seguras)

Comment: La cuenta de correo esta creada con el dominio donde esta el hosting.

Comment: ponle el `$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;` para que te imprima el porque de no connectar y luego posteas eso! no podemos adivinar solo con ese codigo!

Comment: Siempre es bueno que controles la posibilidad de errores, por ejemplo: `if(!$exito) {
    echo 'Error: '. $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message enviado';
}` Ahí debería decirte cuál es el error. Si no muestra nada, aumenta temporalmente el nivel de debug. Ah, y supongo que ya probaste a enviarte un email a ti mismo  y revisar la carpeta spam.